# Sollen order sollten

Tags: grammatical-case

I would like to understand the difference between *sollen* and *sollten* better. For instance, what would be the best way to translate the english

> Small tasks are supposed to be lucrative.

Would you rather say

> Kleine Aufgaben sollen lukrativ sein.

or

> Kleine Aufgaben sollten lukrativ sein.

? If both translations are possible, what are the differences in meaning, if there are any?

Comment: Even a simple statement can have different readings or meanings. For example changing the stress, "**Small** tasks are supposed to be lucrative" vs. "Small tasks are **supposed** to be lucrative" drastically changes the meaning in my opinion. There's no reason to expect that different meanings will be translated into another language the same way.

Answer (score 2):

For an English sentence like

> According to [source], small tasks are supposed to be lucrative.

a German translation would go along the line

> Gemäß [Quelle] sollen kleine Aufgaben lukrativ sein.

But for e.g. an argument

> "Small tasks are supposed to be lucrative. But you made a mess of that one."

I'd translate

> "Kleine Aufgaben sollten (eigentlich) lukrativ sein, aber was hast du daraus gemacht?"

Answer (score 0):

First off: both sentences are correct, but they have different meanings - at least in nuances.

"sollen" is *Infinitiv* (have to/shall) whereas "sollten" is *Konjunktiv* (should).

Your first example:

> Kleine Aufgaben sollen lukrativ sein.

can have two different meanings: the first one is a statement of how it has to be:

> Small tasks are to be lucrative.

So, this is what you wanted to express and the translation of "...are supposed to...". The second possible meaning is the relation of hearsay:

> It is said that small tasks are lucrative.

Which one of these two is meant is usually determined by context.

Your second sentence

> Kleine Aufgaben sollten lukrativ sein.

expresses the wish/suggestion that this is or should be the case:

> Small tasks should be lucrative.

So, depending on circumstance, you could use the second version too.